# How to get a value of __LINE__ of another function (before calling that function)?

Tags: c++, c

For the currently existing test framework I need to pass (*during the first-most call*) to the function a line number of a fragment inside of that function. Something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void func(int line_num)
{
#define LINE_NUM  (__LINE__ + 1)
  if(line_num == __LINE__) // Check the passed arg against the current line.
    printf("OK");
  else
    printf("FAIL");
}

int main(void)
{
  func(LINE_NUM); // Pass to the func the line number inside of that func.
  return 0;
}
```

(this is a minimalistic version of a more complex functionality).

As is the sample code prints "FAIL".

If I pass an absolute value `5`, e.g. `func(5)` then it prints "OK". I don't like the absolute value `5` because if I add one more line in front of the `func` definition then the absolute value will need a correction.

Instead of `#define LINE_NUM  (__LINE__ + 1)` I also tried the following:

1.

```
#define VALUE_OF(x) x
#define LINE_NUM    (VALUE_OF(__LINE__) + 1)
```

2.

```
#define VAL(a,x)    a##x
#define LOG_LINE()    ( VAL( /*Nothing*/,__LINE__) + 1)
```

3.

```
#define VALUE_OF2(x) x
#define VALUE_OF(x)     VALUE_OF2(x)
#define LINE_NUM  (VALUE_OF(__LINE__) + 1)
```

I'm using:

```
gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3
```

In my sample code the value that `func()` gets is 14 (the call site line number + 1).

Comment: so what is the value of LINE_NUM in yr small sample?

Comment: Move your `#define` outside the function

Comment: @pm100 I have added to my question "the value that func() gets is 14".

@smac89 how moving `#define` will solve the problem. Can you answer the question with a sample code?

Comment: @smac89 That won't help. At the preprocessing stage inside and outside are irrelevant.

Comment: The preprocessor does not expand the substitution list in a #define. It expands it when the macro itself is expanded. No amount of macro indirection will change that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot get the preprocessor to expand `__LINE__` in a macro definition. That's not the way the preprocessor works.

But you can create global constants.

```
#include <stdio.h>

static const int func_line_num = __LINE__ + 3;
void func(int line_num)
{
  if(line_num == __LINE__) // Check the passed arg against the current line.
    printf("OK");
  else
    printf("FAIL");
}

int main(void)
{
  func(func_line_num); // Pass to the func the line number inside of that func.
  return 0;
}
```

If you don't like `static const int`, for whatever reason, you could use an enum:

```
enum { FUNC_LINE_NUM = __LINE__ + 3 };
```

Unfortunately, whether you use a global constant or an enum, you have to put the definition at file scope, which might make it somewhat distant from the use point. However, it is not immediately apparent why the precise line number of the test needs to be used, rather than (for example) the first line of the function or even any integer guaranteed to be unique:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// As long as all uses of __LINE__ are on different lines, the
// resulting values will be different, at least within this file.
enum { FUNC_LINE_NUM = __LINE__ };

void func(int line_num)
{
  if(line_num == FILE_LINE_NUM) // Check the passed arg against the appropriate constant.
    printf("OK");
  else
    printf("FAIL");
}

int main(void)
{
  func(func_line_num); // Pass to the func the line number inside of that func.
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you. That was exactly the solution I eventually came up with. But I was hoping there were any better solutions.

So any better solution is still welcome.

Comment: @RobinKuzmin: Out of curiosity, what is your metric for "better"? (IOW, what problem do you have with this solution?)

Comment: For me "better" means `(__LINE__ + 1)` as opposed to `(__LINE__ + 3)`, because if I add lines between `__LINE__ + 3` and `if(line_num == __LINE__)` then the `3` will require correction. Also a var, even const and static (as opposed to a macro), in some cases occupies space at run-time (e.g. if someone accidentally gets an address of that var, ` = &func_line_num`).

Comment: @robin: an `enum` instead of a `static const` would prevent the use of `&`, if that is really a problem. I take your point about the `+ 3`; I don't think it is solvable if you really require that the test be against `__LINE__`.

Comment: Thanks for the enum hint (it's brilliant!). Regarding the rest, I didn't quite get the fragment "rather than .. the first line of the function". My big picture is: The test framework tests our own ASSERT macros in C++. Those macros generate certain _context instance_ that contains the `__LINE__` of where the ASSERT macro is called. Then the ASSERT macro calls callback that compares the actual context instance against the expected context instance. And that expected context instance needs to be filled in with the `__LINE__` of where the ASSERT macro will be triggered (before triggering).

Comment: @robin, ok, that makes sense. It is always helpful to know the reason for apparently obscure requirements.

Answer (score 0):

After @rici 's great [answer and comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47320133/6362941) the closest thing to what I need is the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define LINE_NUM_TESTER() \
    enum { LINE_NUM = __LINE__ }; \
    \
    void line_num_tester(int line_num) \
    { \
      if(line_num == __LINE__) \
        printf("OK\n"); \
      else \
        printf("FAIL. line_num: %d, __LINE__: %d.\n", line_num, __LINE__); \
    }

LINE_NUM_TESTER()

int main(void)
{
  line_num_tester(LINE_NUM);
  return 0;
}
```